# Draw QGLWdiget contents to FBO

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, fbo

I have a `QGraphicsScene` + `QGraphicsView` setup that uses a `QGLWidget` to draw the contents.

I've also made some fragment shaders to add a displacement map and bloom effect to the scene. If I make a `QPainter` object with a `QFramebufferObject` as the device and call the render function of the graphics scene on the `QPainter` object the scene gets rendered to the FBO and I can then use it to make the compositing. This however this has the disadvantage that it uses software rendering and it eats up a lot of resources.

Unfortunately when I try to set a FBO as the current render target and leave the `QGLWidget` to draw on the FBO, the FBO comes out blank (and by blank I mean the color of the `glClearColor` call)

So my question is basically, is there a way to get the contents of a `QGLWidget` on a FBO, or is there any other way of implementing post processing shaders in a `QGLWidget`

Here are the relevant parts of my current code

```
void MyWindow::SwitchRenderContext(RenderType type)
{
    m_renderType = type;
    m_renderArea->SetRenderType(type);
    switch(type)
    {
    case RenderType_Software:
        m_view.setViewport(NULL);
        layout()->removeWidget(&m_view);
        layout()->addWidget(m_renderArea);
        m_view.m_renderWidget = NULL;
        break;
    case RenderType_OpenGL:
        m_view.setViewport(m_renderArea);
        m_view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
        layout()->addWidget(m_renderArea);
        m_view.m_renderWidget = m_renderArea;
        break;
    }
}

void MyGlWidget::initializeGL()
{
    m_initialized = true;
    if(m_dispFbo == NULL)
        m_dispFbo = new QGLFramebufferObject(width(), height());
    if(m_bufFbo == NULL)
        m_bufFbo = new QGLFramebufferObject(width(), height());
    if(m_fbo == NULL)
        m_fbo = new QGLFramebufferObject(width(), height());

    static const float vertex[] = {
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    //initialize vbo
    if(!m_vbo.isCreated())
    {
        m_vboEnabled = m_vbo.create();
        if(m_vboEnabled)
        {
            m_vbo.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
            m_vbo.bind();
            m_vbo.allocate(vertex, sizeof(vertex) );
            m_vbo.release();
        }
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
    m_shadersEnabled = initializeShaders();
}

void MyGlWidget::SetRenderType(RenderType type)
{
    m_renderType = type;
}

void MyGlWidget::DoHardwarePaint()
{
    m_fbo->release();
    QPainter dispPainter(m_dispFbo);
    m_dispScene->RenderScene(&dispPainter);
    dispPainter.end();

    DrawShaders();

    m_fbo->bind();
}

void MyGlWidget::DoSoftwarePaint()
{
    if(!m_shadersEnabled || !m_vboEnabled)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        m_scene->render(&painter);
        return;
    }

    QPainter dispPainter(m_dispFbo);
    m_dispScene->RenderScene(&dispPainter);
    dispPainter.end();

    QPainter painter(m_fbo);
    m_scene->render(&painter);
    painter.end();

    DrawShaders();
    update();

}

void MyGlWidget::DrawShaders()
{
    m_vbo.bind();
    m_bufFbo->bind();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fbo->texture());
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_dispFbo->texture());

    m_displaceShader.bind();
    m_displaceShader.enableAttributeArray("in_verts");
    m_displaceShader.setAttributeBuffer( "in_verts", GL_FLOAT, 0, 4);
    m_displaceShader.setUniformValue("inCol", 0);
    m_displaceShader.setUniformValue("inDisplace", 1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_vbo.size());

    m_bufFbo->release();

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_bufFbo->texture());

    m_bloomShader.bind();
    m_bloomShader.enableAttributeArray("in_verts");
    m_bloomShader.setAttributeBuffer( "in_verts", GL_FLOAT, 0, 4);
    m_bloomShader.setUniformValue("inCol", 0);
    m_bloomShader.setUniformValueArray("offsets", offsets, 8, 2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_vbo.size());

    m_bloomShader.disableAttributeArray("in_verts");
    m_bloomShader.release();

    m_vbo.release();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void MyGlWidget::paintGL()
{
    if(!m_vboEnabled && m_renderType == RenderType_OpenGL)
        return;

    if(m_renderType == RenderType_Software)
    {
        DoSoftwarePaint();
        return;
    }

    DoHardwarePaint();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this has anything to do with QGLWidget *per-se*. If it is actually related to using QGLWidget, then the only thing I can think of has to do with the way Qt switches the bound the render context when it comes time to draw (only one GL context can be bound to a thread at a time, so if QGLWidget defines its own context, trouble will ensue). The basic way to solve this would be to implement context sharing. Can you elaborate a little bit more on your QGLWidget setup?

Comment: thanks for the comment, it was indeed because the QPainter that the view created to render the scene resets the state internally so that the default framebuffer of the current active display gets bound before drawing, but rather than get around this issue, I found out why the QPainter used software rendering when drawing to the QGLFramebufferObject, apparently that's what happens if you don't pass CombinedDepthStencil as the attachment when you create the object. It works as expected now (doesn't hog the CPU anymore), thanks for the tip.